# ReadOnly Access for members of Active Directory Group

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, rhel, active-directory

I have a Linux host that runs on CentOS 7, joined to domain through `realm`.

My goal is to provide ReadOnly access to one of the AD groups say "LinuxRO-USR", the users of this group should only 
be able to sign on using their AD credentials and access their home directory along with other non-sudo commands.

I know adding the following to the sudoers file will also give Sudo access to the users of that group. 
`%LinuxRO-USR@example.com   ALL=(ALL)   ALL`.

Whereas, I want to restricate the access of LinuxRO-USR group such that if one of it's users tries to run any sudo command like `sudo fdisk -l`, 
he should not be provided with the output of it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't I really have anyone who can answer my question!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to have read only for AD members in Linux environment you will need LDAP.
Check the below link and this article will help you:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/summary-direct

Comment: AD is LDAP. Also try to avoid link-only answers as links may become inactive after some time